# Google Play Mobile Services - sign-in in multiple activities

Tags: android, google-play-services

So i'm building a game and using `Google Play Mobile Services`

Everything is working well IF the player is signed in and has an internet connection, else he's continuously presented with the option to login on each page navigation.

My example:
Activity A (main screen), the player is presented with a sign in option, the player taps cancel and proceeds to navigate to Activity B (the gamePlay), here he is presented again with the sign in option.

Activity A and Activity B extend BaseGameActivity. I want it to work so that if the user chooses not to sign in or doesn't have an internet connection to not bug him again until next time he starts the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that should have used fragments, not activities for this as activities disconnect you and connect you to the Play Mobile Services.

Comment: Actually, connecting/disconnecting is done on demand, unless you are deriving your activity from `BaseGameActivity`, which will automatically perform connect/disconnect in `onStart` and `onStop`. You can override this behavior by changing the source code or by not inheriting from this activity and doing it manually (see [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin#signing_the_player_in_at_startup)).